# Why ZFS pool shows different 'Size' vs 'Size on disk'

Tags: network-share, zfs

So I have a shared drive (called 'Share_Drive') on an Ubuntu Server. The folder is publicly shared on my network at home.
The two disks are in a ZFS Mirrored pool:
[image: Pool Status] 
But I noticed in Windows, folders on the networked drive are showing a strange 'Size on disk value'. I would expect it to show double the 'Size' value but that's not the case. Below is a folder of a PC backup that is ~1.53 times the size of the folder amount.
[image: Folder Properties] 
Is this a case of Windows mis-reading the folder's actual size, or something I setup wrong with the mirrored pool?

*Edit*

zfs get all:

```
NAME         PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
Share_Drive  type                  filesystem             -
Share_Drive  creation              Wed Jul 12 20:22 2017  -
Share_Drive  used                  1.57T                  -
Share_Drive  available             194G                   -
Share_Drive  referenced            1.57T                  -
Share_Drive  compressratio         1.00x                  -
Share_Drive  mounted               yes                    -
Share_Drive  quota                 none                   default
Share_Drive  reservation           none                   default
Share_Drive  recordsize            128K                   default
Share_Drive  mountpoint            /Share_Drive           default
Share_Drive  sharenfs              off                    default
Share_Drive  checksum              on                     default
Share_Drive  compression           off                    default
Share_Drive  atime                 on                     default
Share_Drive  devices               on                     default
Share_Drive  exec                  on                     default
Share_Drive  setuid                on                     default
Share_Drive  readonly              off                    default
Share_Drive  zoned                 off                    default
Share_Drive  snapdir               hidden                 default
Share_Drive  aclinherit            restricted             default
Share_Drive  canmount              on                     default
Share_Drive  xattr                 on                     default
Share_Drive  copies                1                      default
Share_Drive  version               5                      -
Share_Drive  utf8only              off                    -
Share_Drive  normalization         none                   -
Share_Drive  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
Share_Drive  vscan                 off                    default
Share_Drive  nbmand                off                    default
Share_Drive  sharesmb              off                    default
Share_Drive  refquota              none                   default
Share_Drive  refreservation        none                   default
Share_Drive  primarycache          all                    default
Share_Drive  secondarycache        all                    default
Share_Drive  usedbysnapshots       0                      -
Share_Drive  usedbydataset         1.57T                  -
Share_Drive  usedbychildren        3.21M                  -
Share_Drive  usedbyrefreservation  0                      -
Share_Drive  logbias               latency                default
Share_Drive  dedup                 off                    default
Share_Drive  mlslabel              none                   default
Share_Drive  sync                  standard               default
Share_Drive  refcompressratio      1.00x                  -
Share_Drive  written               1.57T                  -
Share_Drive  logicalused           1.57T                  -
Share_Drive  logicalreferenced     1.57T                  -
Share_Drive  filesystem_limit      none                   default
Share_Drive  snapshot_limit        none                   default
Share_Drive  filesystem_count      none                   default
Share_Drive  snapshot_count        none                   default
Share_Drive  snapdev               hidden                 default
Share_Drive  acltype               off                    default
Share_Drive  context               none                   default
Share_Drive  fscontext             none                   default
Share_Drive  defcontext            none                   default
Share_Drive  rootcontext           none                   default
Share_Drive  relatime              off                    default
Share_Drive  redundant_metadata    all                    default
Share_Drive  overlay               off                    default
```

Comment: Um, `zfs get all`

Comment: This could be related to the `allocation roundup size` parameter in Samba. As far as I know default is 1MB and files smaller than 1MB are reported as 1MB in size for the sake of performance. You could test with `allocation roundup size = 0` which should disable this feature.